# How can I see required hashrate to mine?

Tags: mining

I'm trying to mine on ropsten testnet. My hashrate is 108905. I think this is very low. Are there any ways to see required hash rate to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a mining calculator to estimate the average amount of time it would take you time successfully mine at that hashrate.

https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

That page is set up for calculations on the main network, so you would first need to work out the combined network hashrate on Ropsten. [This](https://www.ropsten.io/blocks) page shows that it's currently ~0.023 GH/s.

Leaving the other values the same (you might want to tweak them for your specific case - and the actual value of test ether is supposedly $0), and with your hashrate of 108905 H/s (i.e. 0.108905 MH/s)...

```
It will take you an average of 0.05 day to find 1 Block
```

Comment: Glad it helped :-)